# Google segue URL a partir de data-href?

Tags: jquery, google, seo

No meu site há links para determinadas URLs que são abertos com Jquery e o atributo data-href. Esse atributo é inserido numa div normal que funciona como um botão.

Ex.:

```
<div class="open_url" data-href="http://www.exemplo.com.br">
```

O Google segue normalmente essa URL?

Comment: o atributo data-algumacoisa é atributo para armazenar dados, você pode capturar isso usando: `var url = $('.open_url').data('href');` e pegar assim: `<a href="'+url+'">link</a>`

Comment: Perfeito, Ivan. Mas a URL do jeito que deixei em data-href pode ser seguida pelo Google, eu desejo que não seja.

Comment: Rafael, nesse caso talvez você devesse usar o atributo `rel="noindex, nofollow"`no link

Comment: Carlos, mas teria efeito usar o rel= numa DIV como mostro na pergunta? Não há link, e sim uma DIV que representa um botão.

Answer (score 1):

O `data-href` é uma variável que foi criada para o HTML para poder acionar eventos do Java Script, portanto isto é extremamente normal e não, o Google não segue como se fosse um `<a href="">` já que se trata de um atributo de uso totalmente diferente.